# Does TRESOR protect against attacks like HeartBleed

Tags: encryption, linux, heartbleed

I was wondering if the linux TRESOR module (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRESOR) would protect a webserver against HeartBleed or other similar attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. TRESOR only provides a method of storing AES encryption keys in the CPU. It will not prevent an attacker from stealing certificates, user information, password, or whatever else may present in the server's RAM

Comment: Ok. I thought that TRESOR actually encrypted the RAM as well. Although I suppose that if HeartBleed is leaking its own memory rather than someone else's then encryption would not matter.